# Split string on every 500 values with comma

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

how to split this string on every 500 values ending in comma

```
    string val= "1,2,3,4,5,.....................,2000,2001";
    //Solution
    [1,2,3,...,500] 
    [501,502,503,...,1000]
    [1001,1002,...,1500]
```

Comment: "i need solution without loop"...why? If a loop works, why not just use that?

Comment: `i need solution without loop` That's a strange (and probably unachievable) requirement. Implementations will use a loop somewhere, even if it's buried inside a Linq method's implementation.

Comment: As others have mentioned - Without LOOP anywhere in the scene - this is really difficult to achieve. Unless say all your Values are single character. So that would mean. 500 + 499 = 999 would be the index where first 500 CSV list ends and so on.

Comment: @fubo - Assume we do find a regex that can Split by 500th Comma. What will Regex.Match(es) return? A List of Matches - which has to be inspected using a loop; isnt it?

Comment: Agree with your solution (and a good regex) however, for OP to finally Present/Look through the results, a loop on string[] result is needed.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava the question was about the determination without loop - op didn't say anything about further processing.

Comment: Does anyone think that Regex is implemented without using any loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match the string with the following regex instead (where 499 is 500 minus 1):

```
(?:[^,]+,){0,4}[^,]+
```

Demo (for splitting at every 5 commas here): https://regex101.com/r/nbRxdv/2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "no loops" you mean you're happy to let LINQ use loops internally, maybe something like this:

```
        string s = "your,comma,string";
        string[] ss = s.Split(',');

        Print500(ss, 0);

    private void Print500(IEnumerable<string> ies, int skip)
    {
        if (skip > ies.Count())
            return;

        Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Join(",", ies.Skip(skip).Take(500)));

        Print500(ies, skip + 500);
    }
```

I haven't run it, so it might have some minor issues..

Comment: String.Split used 1 Loop. IEnumerable.Count() used 1 Loop. string.Join() took another and Skip() and Take() took there own loops (crudely).

Comment: My code contains no loops. Note the first line of the post. If you're insisting that no loops requirement goes all the way down to the BIOS I think you'll be out of luck on pretty much anything

Comment: I am gonna use this Recursion idea to write something now....

Comment: Maybe Ramapriyan should have posted on codegolf.. :)

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava Recursion is a form of looping… :)